# Issue with CSS Loader in Vue app using webpack

Tags: vue.js, webpack, css-loader

Working on my first Vue app, and I'm now having issues when I run the build script. It claims I have an unknown "minimize" property in the options object, but damned if I can find where. I'm assuming some sort of dependency conflict? Any thoughts on how to untangle this?

Error below:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?minimize!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-329f0f9e","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
Module build failed: ValidationError: Invalid options object. CSS Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'minimize'. These properties are valid:
   object { url?, import?, modules?, sourceMap?, importLoaders?, localsConvention?, onlyLocals?, esModule? }
    at validate (C:\code\my-vue-app\node_modules\css-loader\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:85:11)
    at Object.loader (C:\code\my-vue-app\node_modules\css-loader\dist\index.js:34:28)
 @ ./node_modules/vue-style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?minimize!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-329f0f9e","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue 4:14-287
 @ ./src/App.vue
 @ ./src/main.js
```

Here is my package.json file:

```js
{
  "name": "my-vue-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --hide-modules"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "vue": "^2.5.11"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "file-loader": "^1.1.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "vue-loader": "^13.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.4",
    "webpack": "^3.6.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.1"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the `webpack.config.js` file as well. (Note: I commented out the `webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin` bit; it had no effect.)

```js
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.sass$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
            // Since sass-loader (weirdly) has SCSS as its default parse mode, we map
            // the "scss" and "sass" values for the lang attribute to the right configs here.
            // other preprocessors should work out of the box, no loader config like this necessary.
            'scss': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            'sass': [
              'vue-style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader?indentedSyntax'
            ]
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Comment: show your webpack config. Probably you have in the config some problems.

Comment: Thanks, @Guarana. I've added it to the question.

Comment: try comment this code `new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({ minimize: true })`

Comment: yeah, that's the first thing I tried. No change.

Comment: you have the problem with production build or dev ?

Comment: just production. Dev still works fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207613/discussion-between-guarana-and-acullen72).

Answer (score 1):

If you're working on your first Vue app, you should really use the [Vue CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html). It manages a basic Webpack configuration for you.

It comes with SCSS, SASS, and less support out of the box... as well as hot reloading, babel, jest, linting etc.

`npx vue create my-app` will give you a working application.

Most production apps use Vue CLI because managing your own loader dependencies like this is a sure-fire way to spend a lot of time configuring webpack instead of programming.

Comment: Thanks for the tip; will research that now.

Comment: ...I think what's happening in your error is that Vue's style loader doesn't support that version of the css style loader.

Comment: This kind of version mis-match is what Vue CLI is designed to solve

Comment: I think that it's good to understand how to use Webpack before just switching to using Vue CLI as a crutch.

Comment: I agree, but he's on Webpack 3 and has a version mismatch issue with various loaders that aren't documented extensively with how to handle backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing

```
new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
  minimize: true
})
```

This is an old plugin and I believe that it is passing an option `minimize: true` to `css-loader`. `css-loader` doesn't support this, so it is throwing an error.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that with no appreciable change in result.